# Looking for a cloud based http task scheduler

Tags: api, http, saas, rest

Looking for a SAAS solution that will issue a scheduled request to an HTTP URL, e.g. http://mydomain.com/tasks/dosomething

This would trigger some maintenance tasks on my app. Email notification on failure essential. Response time and HTTP auth desirable but not required.

It's not too dissimilar to an uptime app like Pingdom or Uptime robot, but I don't want to issue many requests from different servers.

Or am I barking up the wrong tree here? Main goal is to disconnect the maintenance events from the server itself.

Comment: I think I would need a little more detail about your setup. Things like Celery on Django could work with part of this, but I'm having a little trouble visualising your workflow and how this would help.